# 3D visualization of kinect output during run time

Tags: c++, 3d, visualization, kinect-v2

I am using kinect v2 for skeleton tracking, hand trajectory etc in visual studio (cpp). I want my kinect output in 3d visualization. Can any one please suggest me easy way to visualize kinect output in 3D in windows

Thanks in advance

Comment: +Close as too broad ... you need to be more specific ... what kind of input you got what you wan as expected output, Which gfx lib etc ... take a look at [Align already captured rgb and depth images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35914008/2521214) it uses oldstyle OpenGL  for visualization of kinect data ... Also Kinect SDK shoould contain examples for this too (at least the one for Kinect v1 does even in C++)

Comment: i want to monitor human standing in front of kinect v2 camera. i would like to visualize gestures performed by him in 3d visualization and also when he tries to pick an object i want to have some colour change in the object picked in my visualization.

Comment: that is too vague ... what kind of data you got? point `cloud , BR mesh` unaligned Depth/RGB frames ? with what attributes... what kind of render 2D/3D ? what kind of color change (object segmentation based recoloring? informative vector lines/polylines HUD overlay)  What gfx lib and platform are you using (native C++ does not support graphic output)? Where exactly are you stuck? any code ?

Answer (score 0):

I developed a prototype project for 3D interaction including real-time visualization of the kinect input in 3D world using point cloud. you can check out my project in github.

https://github.com/shanilfernando/VRInteraction

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uAO1ALRHjQQ

Right hand side of the video is the 3D real time point cloud visualization by 3D registration using CUDA.